# Font Anti-Aliasing on iPad SDK

Tags: antialiasing, uifont

I'm using a custom pixel font on the iPad SDK, and I'm trying to find a way to disable font anti-aliasing for UIFont. Pixel fonts usually work best when they don't have Anti-aliasing. I disable it easily in Photoshop when I create static resources, but this time I need a dynamic output with the custom font.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work if you are subclassing a UILabel or similar:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)r {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState( context );
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts( context , false );
    [super drawRect:r];
    CGContextRestoreGState( context );
}
```

If that does not work you can try these calls too:

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing( context , false );
CGContextSetShouldAntialias( context , false );
```