# Font is displayed differently on iPad than in Photoshop

Tags: ipad, fonts, photoshop

I am wondering what might be the explanation to the fact that a font is displayed differently on iPad than in Photoshop?

The font in question is DIN 1451 Std. We've had an awful lot of headaches with integrating it into the iPad app and now we see that it's not rendered the same as in Photoshop: the characters are more curved, a bit stretched and not even sizes are consistent, 16px in Photoshop being the equivalent of 13px on iPad.

We've tried turning off the antiAliasing (by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695638/font-anti-aliasing-on-ipad-sdk)) but that didn't do the trick either.

Thank you.

Comment: What context are you talking about? A web site?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is the photoshop doesn't go of off pixels on fonts but rather points. So 16px font will never be exactly 16pt in Photoshop. They may be somewhat similar but never exact and the font choice can dramatically effect that difference due to kerning and leading with the font. From what I understand fonts are rendered very differently in photoshop than say a mobile / web app.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the resolution in Photoshop. Go to Image > Image Size and make sure the Resolution is 72 dpi.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, the resolution is 72 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Well we finally have found the reason of this behaviour: for some reason iOs did not get very well with the font file so in some cases letters or even whole words defaulted to Helvetica.