# UIFont without Anti-aliasing

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I am making a retro app and I want to use fonts without anti-aliasing. Is there a way to assign fonts without anti-aliasing to UILabels and controls?

The other response (the reason that this question has been identified as duplicate) is in Objective-C. I translate the code to Swift 4, but It doesn't work:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    ctx?.saveGState()
    ctx?.setShouldSmoothFonts(false)
    ctx?.setAllowsAntialiasing(false)
    ctx?.setShouldAntialias(false)
    ctx?.setAllowsFontSmoothing(false)
    super.draw(rect)
    ctx?.restoreGState()
}
```

I am looking for a way to display the font in the same way that Windows 98 do, but maybe is not possible... [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Anti-Aliasing on iPad SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695638/font-anti-aliasing-on-ipad-sdk) (that post is not actually related to iPad)

Comment: That response is in Objective-C. I created the Swift version, but it don't seems to work...

Comment: The code do work, but to see difference you need upscale your label

Comment: Ok. Maybe my question is not good. I am looking for a way to display text in the same way that Windows 98 do...

Comment: I see. Maybe it's easier to find windows98-style font.